# Error: Read access denied for null

Tags: sobject

Does any one have any idea why I am getting this error 
when I try to save {!sobj.c}

> Error: Read access denied for null

my code

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!sobjlst}" var="sobj">
    <apex:column >
        <apex:repeat value="{!wcls}" var="sobjfd">
            alert({!sobjfd.fieldname});
            <apex:variable var="c" value="{!sobjfd.fieldname}" />
                alert({!c});
                //sobj is the list of all the objects we are using like this <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!sobjlst}" var="sobj">
            <apex:inputField value="{!sobj.c}"/>
            <!-- <apex:inputField value="{!sobjfd.objectName.get(c)}"/>-->
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

list

```
public List<sObject> sobjlst {get; set;}
```

My wrapper class :

```
public class wrapperClass {
    public list<Schema.SObjectField> fieldname {get; set;}
    public SObject objectName {get; set;}
    public wrapperClass(SObject objectName, list<Schema.SObjectField> fieldname) {
        this.fieldname = fieldname;
        this.objectName = objectName;
    }
}
```

Please do help me how can I display the object with the name of the fields so that it can be inputfield. I need fields in the wrapper to be added as dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Change the code in Visualforce page like this.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!sobj[c]}"   />
```

or

```
<apex:inputField value="{!sobj[sobjfd.fieldname]}"   />
```

Comment: sharan, to post code or VF you can select it and click the {} button in the editor. That'll make sure it's all shown.

Comment: Thanks Samuel. But I could not find that {} button.

Comment: apologies, in this new designs it's the button with the binary 1 and 0's.  I've gone and editted the post for you.